# React setState doesnt set proper value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got initial values set:

```
constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
        progress: 0,
        syncStatus: 'wait',
        queueData: [],
        queueDataDone: [],
        mappedAttributes: [],
        parent_id: 0
    }
}
```

then I've got a function:

```
async loopProducts( products ) {
    let that = this
    let product_id

    return await Promise.all( products.map( async (element, key) => {
        console.log(that.state.parent_id) 

        let productData = {
            name: element['Nazwa'],
            short_description: element['Krótki opis'],
            description: element['Opis'],
            backorders: element['Pozwalać na zamówienie oczekujące?'] == 0 ? 'yes' : 'no',
            sku: element['Sku'],
            slug: element['Slug'],
            type: products.length == 1 ? 'simple' : 'variable',
            parent_id: products.length == 1 ? null : this.state.parent_id,
        }

        await Import(productData).then(function(result) {
            that.setState({ parent_id: result.id})
        });

        console.log(that.state.parent_id)

        return products
        
    }))
}
```

Why the first console.log prints everytime "0" but the second prints correct value? Why state of parent_id at the beginning of map function is always "0"?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `loopProducts` function, `constructor` is automatically called.
So `parent_id` is initialized to 0. And `map` is not `for` loop. it is loop callback functions. So, when start loop, every callback functions work with `parent_id` is 0